# Powershell - replace variable with it's content in HTML file

Tags: html, powershell

I have HTML file:

1.html

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Password Reminder</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <p>
        Dear user, your password expires in: <strong>$($days)</strong> days.
        </p>
    </body>
   </html>
```

I created function which reads file content and replace `$days` variable with actual variable value.

```
function ReadTemplate($days) {
    $template_content = Get-Content "C:\PasswordReminder\1.html" -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
    #$template_content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($template)
    $template_content = $template_content -replace "{}",$days
    return $template_content
}
```

But when calling it

```
$content = ReadTemplate -days 2
```

Instead of Dear user, your password expires in: 2 days.

I'm getting

Dear user, your password expires in: **$($days)** days.

Instead of `$($days)` specified `{0}` but nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$template_content = $template_content.replace('$($days)',$days)`

Answer (score 2):

As `$($days)` is in fact a valid PowerShell variable syntax, you probably just want to [substitute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.3#variable-substitution) it:

```
$Days = 17
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Escape` method:

```
$template_content -replace ([regex]::Escape('$($days)')), $days
```